# Accessing XPath query results when all that is returned is a LibXML object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xpath, libxml2

```
require 'net/http'; require 'libxml'

data = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://myurl.com')).body
source = LibXML::XML::Parser.string(data).parse

tables = source.find('//table')
```

returns

```
 => #<LibXML::XML::XPath::Object:0x1f4f50>
```

How do I access this? There are at least 11 tables there.

p.s. I can't use Nokogiri on my current setup.

Answer (score 1):

You access the XPath results by asking for the node item like this.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'libxml'

# Sample text with a few tables
xml=<<END
<html>
  <table id="t1"><tr><td>foo</td></tr></table>
  <table id="t2"><tr><td>goo</td></tr></table>
  <table id="t3"><tr><td>hoo</td></tr></table>
</html>
END

# Parse the text into tables
source = LibXML::XML::Parser.string(xml).parse
tables = source.find('//table')

# The XPath #each iterator does each XML node
tables.each {|node|
  puts node["id"] 
}
```

If you have an older version of libxml:

```
- puts node["id"] 
+ puts node.property("id")
```

Comment: 1.9.2p318 :013 > tables.each {|node| puts node["id"]}
 => nil 
1.9.2p318 :014 > tables.each {|node| puts node["class"]}
 => nil 
Doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Matthew, can you provide more info? What happens when you run it? The code above runs on my setup (Ruby 1.9.3, libxml-ruby 2.3.2, Ubuntu 11.10). Try using node.property -- I just added this info to the answer.

Comment: I tried your exact code (with the HTML you provided), which works :) but now try importing code from a real web page like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles - it returns nil :( - so weird!

Comment: Have managed to work something out with Hpricot, don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

Manage to work it out with Hpricot!